# generic object using policies / templates

Tags: c++

There are object behaviors I need over and over again, including ownership, pipeline-like interaction, statemachine behavior etc. I thought this to be a good opportunity to try out a new design pattern called "policies" in a quite famous book about c++.

Now I have difficulties creating a class

```
template <
  class T,
  template <typename T> class pOwnership
  template <typename T> class pInteraction
>
class object : public pOwnership<T>, public pInteraction<T>
{...}
```

which should take 2 policies dealing with ownership and interaction. 
For example, pOwnership has a method

```
void add(T &obj)
```

which adds an object to the internal list

```
std::vector<T*>.
```

(using another ownership-policy, for example when I don't need ownership, *void add(T &obj)* could also be undeclared, resulting in compile-time errors if using the wrong application code)

**Now the type T should be the final policy host class**, meaning the *object* class:

```
typedef template<object, pOwnershipRecursive, pInteractionPipeline> myObject;
```

Of course *object* is a template-type itself, resulting in compiler errors.

How can one realize a class like myObject?

Comment: "a quite famous book about c++"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expected to use CRTP:

```
class myObject : public object<myObject, 
                 pOwnershipRecursive, 
                 pInteractionPipeline>
{
   // your real content here: 
   // an object that consists solely of policies is probably useless
};
```

Comment: that was helpful, thanks. Even if I wished there was a different method not needing another derivation (using CRTP there is policies -> object -> myObject each including dynamic polymorphism)